# Regex to Match mRNA Sequences

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics

In eukaryotes spliced mRNA has three key properties:

1. mRNA starts with a start codon (ATG)
2. The coding part of the mRNA ends with one of three stop codons (TAA/TAG/TGA)
3. Immediately after the stop codon there is a 'poly(A) tail'. The poly(A) tail is a run of many adenines (A's) attached to the 3' end of the coding sequence after transcription. In reality there maybe hundreds of A's in the poly(A) tail, but usually the end of the mRNA/cDNA is not entirely sequenced, so there may be as few as 5 A's following the stop codon.

So basically, an mRNA sequence should start with ATG, be followed by any number of As, Cs, Ts or Gs, then TAA or TAG or TGA, then 5 or more As.

My (python) regex is this: `^ATG[ATCG]*T(AA|AG|GA)A{5}A*$`

However, this is matching sequences which have further characters after the poly(A) tail as if the `$` character is not being recognized. What am I doing wrong?

*Valid Examples:*

```
ATGCTGATGATGATGATAGAAAAA
ATGTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

*Invalid Examples:*

```
ATGCTGATGXTGATGATAGAAAAA
TATGCTGATGXTGATGATAGAAAAA
ATGTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC
```

EDIT (My full code):

```
file = open('potential_mRNA.fasta')
alignment = SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta')
mRNA_seqs = []
mRNA_pattern = r'^ATG[ATCG]*T(AA|AG|GA)A{5}A*$'
for mrna in alignment:
    sequence = str(mrna.seq)
    if re.search(mRNA_pattern, sequence):
        mRNA_seqs.append(sequence)
```

Comment: Please provide example strings (valid/invalid). Maybe a parser would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This is a homework assignment so I'm required to use a regex. In terms of example strings, would it be better to create simple cases or include the actual sequences I am working on? Only because they are quite long (~2000 characters).

Comment: Maybe the problem is with repeated TAA/TAG/TGA inside the string? Try `^ATG(?:(?!T(?:AA|AG|GA))[ATCG])*T(?:AA|AG|GA)A{5,}$`

Comment: @Sian a simple case is better

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that expression but that resulted in no matches at all (rather than too many). I'm not sure why as I don't exactly understand your syntax. I will edit my question to include simple examples of valid and invalid strings!

Comment: Your regex looks ok. I would change the group `(AA|AG|GA)` to a non-capturing one `(?:AA|AG|GA)` but that is probably not the problem. Please add your code

Comment: @GiladShnoor Done

Comment: Your regex is fine - https://regex101.com/r/Q6jSrN/1

Comment: @Sian it looks like you are appending the str of the var seq which you never declared you should append sequence instead

Comment: @GiladShnoor Oh, sorry, that's a typo. It should read `mRNA_seqs.append(sequence)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay, honestly at this point I'm thinking the problem may be with my professor's grading program rather than my code haha because I have fixed the problem with accepting the extra sequences yet the grader still says my answer is wrong

Comment: @Sain could be a problem is in the grading program. I ran a version of your code base on the examples you gave and it seems to work (Used strings instead of the file). The only other place I think the problem might be is in the way your program gets the strings. You could try printing out `sequence` and making sure it's correct

Comment: Did you finally get the answer? How can we answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

It works that way because the first `*` is greedy and tries to match as much as possible, matches all your suffixes and regex parser never goes beyond parsing `[ATCG]`.

The `$` should however make it work as you would expect so your regex is perfectly valid for your task, maybe there is some unknown conditions that I couldn't see with your question.

Try `^ATG[ATCG]*?T(?:AA|AG|GA)A{5,}$`

I've used lazy `*?` instead of `*`, and also a non-capturing group `(?:)` and `A{5,}` instead of `A{5}A*` just to optimize.